# Wicket - Best way to implement complex components

Tags: java, forms, components, wicket, reusability

I've started an application wit a lot of forms in with Wicket so I'm looking for how to write components well, reusable and mainly, easy to maintain.

Reading [best practices](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_cut_small_classes_and_methods) from the guide it says to decouple more complex components (in the example a form with labels and panels) make it self-contained defining a method to create each form component:

```
public class BlogEditPage extends WebPage {
...
    private Form<Blog> createBlogEditForm() {
        Form<Blog> form = newBlogEditForm();
        form.add(createHeadlineField());
        form.add(createContentField());
        form.add(createTagField());
        form.add(createViewRightPanel());
        form.add(createCommentRightPanel());
        form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        return form;
    }

    // more methods here
}
```

At first it sounds weird to me, but considering each component can have it's own complexity, validation rules, it makes sense (this way it can be easily reused too).

But in the [same section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_do_not_use_factories_for_components) it also says to not create factories to components.. now it's weird cause the snippet above works like a factory to forms, and the page have factories to form components. Even the methods that creates form components being private, only form will can use it, and reusability is lost. So considering the second recommendation, these methods (that is implicit component factories) are not a good practice.

Any clarification of how to create complex components are welcome (with some code example will be better).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use this approach and it works ok.

The methods you show are not factories. Look at the example from the docs. 
They have something like `LabelFactory.createLabel(id, model);` But that's not the case with the methods you have shown above.

In the methods you show remove the word `create`. Our components look like this:

```
   private AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable table() {
      List<AbstractColumn> columns = new ArrayList<>();
      columns.add(new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Login"), "login", "login"));
      columns.add(new PropertyColumn(Model.of("First Name"), "firstName", "firstName"));
      columns.add(new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Last Name"), "lastName", "lastName"));
      AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable dt = new AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable("table", columns, new UserProvider(), 50);
      dt.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
      return dt;
   }
```

There is no factory. An additional convention we use is that the name of the method and the wicket id of the components has to be the same. This eases navigation in code.

Comment: That&#39;s the point: the word &#39;create&#39; in methods are used in the guide, not by me..  It clearly says to separate the creation of components into methods in section 25.15

Comment: To clarify, in my question I'm comparing the recommended snippet listed, with this section (https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_do_not_use_factories_for_components).

Comment: Yes, i understand. The show there just an antipattern. Just use the convention you showed in your question and mine convention.

Comment: Understood.. so if I understand correctly, in guide example the create methods will be private too? If yes, only the class will be able to use the form-creator and form-components-creator.. what advantage to wrapping components creation to methods, considering reusability wil be lost?